# echo records from database not displaying?

Tags: php, html

I have a select option in my `index.php` and inside the select I echo a record from my database, but it displays this value "--".

How can I display the record from database to display options?

All the code works fine I just want the records from the database to display.

**class.user.php**

```
public function getID($ID)
{
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM rlbet WHERE ID=:ID");
$stmt->execute(array(":ID"=>$ID));
$editRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $editRow;
}
```

**here is my php**

```
$Reason_for_Deduction = isset($_GET['Reason_for_Deduction']) ? $_GET['Reason_for_Deduction'] : '';

if(isset($_GET['ID']))
    {
    $ID = $_GET['ID'];
    extract($LTID->getID($ID));
```

**Here is my html:**

```
<select name="Province" class="form-control" id="category" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
     <option selected="selected"value="<?php echo $Province; ?>">--- </option>
     <option value="Ajhsfg">Ajhsfg</option>
     <option value="dsfdf">dsfdf</option>
     <option value="jhfdsg">jhfdsg</option>
     <option value="sfg">sfg</option>
     <option value="jhsfg">jhsfg</option>
     <option value="jhsfg">jhsfg</option>
     <option value="jhsdgf">jhsdgf</option>
</select>
```

[image]

as you can see in the image i echoed most of them but when i try to echoed it using the select its not appearing..

Comment: <option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $Province; ?>"><?php echo $Province; ?></option> have you try this?

Comment: Use this `<option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $Province; ?>">--- <?php echo $Province; ?></option>`

Comment: ok wait..i'll try it

Comment: i've tried both you codes but now its not showing anything

Comment: that means your $Province contain null value.

Comment: `<option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $Province; ?>">--- <?php echo $Province; ?></option>` and problem not solved, then problem is that you are not getting variable value from database, it is empty show your php file.

Comment: @kier can u show how u fetch the array from your database?

Comment: @HamzaZafeer i'll update my question

Comment: @AshrafKamarudin i'll update mty question

Comment: i already updated my question

Comment: @kier so where did u assign any value to $province? in what i see..you does not assign any value to ur $province so it will echo nothing

Comment: but when i try it to a input i echo the province inside my database..

Comment: i updated my code..i put a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

```
try this code 
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT  Province FROM table";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {  /// output data of each row ?>

  <select name="Province" class="form-control" id="category" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <?php  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      ?>
      <option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $row["Province"]; ?>"> </option>
    </select>
    <?php
  }
} else {
 echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="<?php echo $Province; ?>" selected><?php echo $Province; ?></option>
```

Duplicate the PHP echo between the option tags.

Comment: i tried you code but there's nothing is displaying now

Comment: well well .. looked again.... my bad... `<option value="<?php echo $Province; ?>" selected><?php echo $Province; ?> </option>` ... change selected="selected" to just selected AFTER the value tag

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
<select>
<?php while ($data = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("your query here"))){ extract($data);?>
<option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $Province; ?>">
<?php echo $Province; ?>
</option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the same value for id and name in the Select

```
<select name="Province" class="form-control" id="Province" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
 <option selected="selected"value="<?php echo $Province; ?>">--- </option>
 <option value="Ajhsfg">Ajhsfg</option>
 <option value="dsfdf">dsfdf</option>
 <option value="jhfdsg">jhfdsg</option>
 <option value="sfg">sfg</option>
 <option value="jhsfg">jhsfg</option>
 <option value="jhsfg">jhsfg</option>
 <option value="jhsdgf">jhsdgf</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it displays me this --- what i want to display in my select is the province insde my database

Comment: can You try like  <option selected="selected"value="<?php echo $Province; ?>">"<?php echo $Province; ?>" </option> ..

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not getting any data echoed, because you've actually not fetched the data correctly in the first place.

Here's a sneak peek on how to do it correctly:

```
<?php
    function getData() {
        // Connect to database
        $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database");

        // SELECT query to get the value from database
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Data` = ?";

        // Prepare statement, bind the parameter, execute and get result
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query)) {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $data);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

            // If the data entered in the query exists in the database fetch it
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                echo $data["Data"];
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                mysqli_close($connection);
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

1. You must supplant `username`, `password` and `database` with the respective values for your database.
2. You must supplant `Data` with the name of the column of your table you are looking to check.
3. You can supplant `$data` with a variable name that you like or leave it as it is.

---

Then you can call the function and have the result echoed:

```
<option value="<?php getData();?>" selected></option>
```

Comment: i actually echoed it.i just want to do is that to display the record of province in the select..because it is a update page

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT  Province FROM table";
  $results = mysql_query($sql);
echo"<select>"
foreach($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
{
echo"<option value ".$row['yourValue'].">".$row['yourValue']."</option>"
}
echo"</select>"
```